# My robot is driving to slow with gazebo_ros_diff_drive

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi

My simulated pioneer robot is going to slow with the gazebo_ros_diff_drive
It think there is a math error :-)

Greetings

gazebo 2.2.1, ros hydro, ubuntu 12.04 64bit

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5218/my-robot-is-driving-to-slow-with-gazebo_ros_diff_drive/) by [Markus Bader](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/491/markus-bader/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-01-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi

I figured it out there was a math problem:
The wheel velocity was computed incorrect. The wheel speed has to be divided by the radius and not the diameter.
changing the lines 309/310 to solved my problem

```
joints_[LEFT]->SetVelocity(0, wheel_speed_[LEFT] / (wheel_diameter_ / 2.0));
joints_[RIGHT]->SetVelocity(0, wheel_speed_[RIGHT] / (wheel_diameter_ / 2.0));
```

I will make a pull request for my solution

Greetings
Max

---

Originally posted by [Markus Bader](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/491/markus-bader/) with karma: 61 on 2014-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1